# Jssor scale in proportion by height and width of container

Tags: jquery, css, jssor

searching around I only found that people either scale by height or width, which I can do however I need to do both.

My gallery container is set in percentages although I don't think matters.

Essentially I want my jssor gallery to adjust according to it's container's dimensions.

Looking at the full screen solution here http://www.jssor.com/testcase/full-screen-slider.source.html it as a JS error so it doesn't work.

Right now I scale by height which works to some degree, however as the width gets smaller the image gallery will be cut off (as the container has overflow:hidden) on some smaller widths as it is adjusting by the height of the container to stay in proportion but doesn't consider the width of the container too, essentially the width is longer than the container width.

```
function ScaleSlider() {

var parentHeight = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientHeight;

if (parentHeight) {

    if ((parentHeight - 70) > 0) {

        parentHeight = parentHeight - 70;

    }


    var sliderOriginalWidth = jssor_slider1.$OriginalWidth();

    var sliderOriginalHeight = jssor_slider1.$OriginalHeight();

    var newWidthToFitParentContainer = parentHeight / sliderOriginalHeight * sliderOriginalWidth;


    jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(newWidthToFitParentContainer);
}
else
    window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);


}
```

Comment: For long run, we need a new api $ResizeCanvas. But for now, jssor slider should always keep aspect ratio to scale. Btw, the http://www.jssor.com/testcase/full-screen-slider.source.html works.

Comment: Yes that's correct it does keep it's aspect ratio which is what I want and that's the problem, when I scale width by height at some point the width of the slider will be more than the width of it's container. Your example has a JS error if you resize the width you will see.

Comment: So, we need new api $ResizeCanvas. It can't be done in a short time. Btw,  there is no js error in the demo link, even I resize window.

Comment: Ok will await the API, I have pasted a possible solution below. I guess for my needs I have the added complexity of the the gallery's container being fluid (percentage) in both height and width, not just one.

Answer (score 0):

Ok since JSSOR has said there is no current solution here is what I've done in the mean time.

When scaling by height you have to also detect whether the width of the gallery will exceed it's container and calculate by width instead.

```
var parentHeight = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientHeight;

                if (parentHeight) {


                    var sliderOriginalWidth = jssor_slider1.$OriginalWidth();

                    var sliderOriginalHeight = jssor_slider1.$OriginalHeight();

                    var newWidthToFitParentContainer = parentHeight / sliderOriginalHeight * sliderOriginalWidth;

        if (newWidthToFitParentContainer > jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth) {

            //scale differently if the width of the slider is greater than the parent

            jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth-30);


        }
        else {

            jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(newWidthToFitParentContainer);

        }
                }
                else
                    window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
```